# Insert query not executing from within a block

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, procedure

I have created a procedure in oracle pl/sql.

It consists of an insert query, the insert query if executed from outside the procedure is working fine, but as soon as I run the procedure with the insert query, the procedure is executed successfully but the inserted row does not reflect in the table.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DEMO_PROC

(

step11 NVARCHAR2,
v_name NVARCHAR2
)
AS

BEGIN

Insert Into table123
(Vname, decision, Decision_Reason, Decision_Date, 
stepN)
Select Distinct Vname,decision_Reason,
Decision_Date, stepN From demoTest123_history
Where  Vname= v_name And QUEUE_NAME=step11 
ORDER BY DECISION_DATE;

commit;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where  Vname= v_name And QUEUE_NAME=step11

You haven't assigned any value to the variables, therefore the query doesn't return anything. Either assign a value in the block, or pass it as IN parameter and then pass the value while you execute the procedure:

```
EXECUTE DEMO_PROC(v_name ==> 'value', queue_name ==> 'value')
```

Also, using `ORDER BY` in `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement makes no sense as the rows are not stored in any particular order. Remove the ORDER BY.